# Ruby FFI callback return values

Tags: ruby, ffi

I'm trying to get my head around FFI in ruby. Is there no way to make use of the return from an FFI callback?

Here's my minimal example:

```
require 'ffi'

class Foo
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib File.expand_path('fun.o')
  callback :incoming_rpc, [:string], :string
  attach_function :do_some_work, [:incoming_rpc, :string], :string, blocking: true

  def initialize
    @callback = build_callback_runner
    output = do_some_work(@callback, "Ruby init...")
    puts "Output: #{output.inspect}"
  end

  def build_callback_runner
    FFI::Function.new(:string, [:string]) do |name|
      puts "Inside runner: #{name}"
      "DO YOU READ ME?"
    end
  end

end

Foo.new
```

Here is the C function I'm calling: yep, I know it's not brilliant C, my original receiver was in go, which also fails in exactly the same way. (I won't promise I'm writing brilliant go, either)

```
// Name: fun.c
// Compiled with: gcc -shared -o fun.o fun.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* (*callbkfn)(char*);

extern char* do_some_work(callbkfn fn, char* name);

char* do_some_work(callbkfn fn, char* userdata) {
  printf("do_some_work param: %s\n", userdata);
  printf("callback output: %s\n", fn(strdup("Hello from C")));
  return strdup("Returned from C");
}
```

Output:

```
do_some_work param: Ruby init...
Inside runner: Hello from C
callback output: (null)
Output: "Returned from C"
```

It's that null in the callback output I can't seem to shake. How do you pass the "return" value of a callback FFI::Function or callback proc back into C? The FFI documentation always seems to set callbacks as `:void`, and I'm guessing the answer is somewhere on the pointers page - but I'm drawing a blank (much like my callback)

Comment: For some reason, I could make it work for `int` return values, but not `string` :(

Comment: @Ja͢ck one obviously cannot return _strings_ (whatever it would mean in the [tag:c] world,) from programs. OS has to clean up the stack once the program has exited, otherwise, each time you run a program, you’ll experience a memory leak. And OS cannot clean up the stack of unknown size, as if `char *` was allowed as a return value. That’s why e.g. all shell utilities use _return codes_, not _return anything_.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin this isn’t returning the string from a program, so the c code would still have an opportunity to free() the memory before exit

Comment: @Ja͢ck AFAICT it actually is. It does return _something_ from a shared library function, which is essentially the same because there is no way to free this memory afterward. Imagine I have a long-running process that is calling this function subsequently. The library stays loaded. Who is supposed to free the memory and how?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin are you saying that the returned value from `fn()` can't be freed inside `do_some_work()`?

Comment: Oh, indeed, I missed that it’s a callback failing; anyway, it seems that [tag:ruby] cleans up the stack since it’s owning the memory in this scenario.

Comment: anyway, fwiw, you can look at [this example](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/master/samples/qsort.rb) which makes this work for `int` return types; i haven't found any articles that describe a callback that returns a complex type

Comment: Thanks everyone - quite glad I'm not going crazy / doing something stupid. @AlekseiMatiushkin Normally I'd agree with you, but I feel like the impossibility should also apply to every other string (or char*) that gets passed in and out of C-land, and in this example others work fine. So I don't feel like it's a question of being technically impossible.

Comment: And thanks @Ja͢ck - I don't expect the FFI library to police memory leaks, but you might be right - just because I don't expect them to, doesn't mean they are not. Sounds more like a documentation hole or maybe a missed feature (though I doubt I'm the only person to have come up against this). Oh well. Thanks again all!

Comment: I was curious about this, so did some investigation. The code that wraps the Proc and [converts the return value from a Ruby type to a C type](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/ad524cb016fc788861d76e43a5067b8d441a76bc/ext/ffi_c/Function.c#L767-L845) doesn’t have an entry for strings, so it falls through to the [default case](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/ad524cb016fc788861d76e43a5067b8d441a76bc/ext/ffi_c/Function.c#L842-L844) which just sets it to 0...

Comment: It’s fairly easy to hack in an extra case here to return a `char *`, and while that seems to work I don’t know the details of Ruby or FFI enough to know if that would be safe with GC etc.

Comment: Thanks @matt - excellent investigation - make that an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this to work if you use a `:pointer` as the return type rather than `:string` (which is just a pointer to `char` anyway):

```ruby
class Foo
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib File.expand_path('fun.o')
  callback :incoming_rpc, [:string], :pointer # <- change here
  attach_function :do_some_work, [:incoming_rpc, :string], :string, blocking: true

  def initialize
    @callback = build_callback_runner
    output = do_some_work(@callback, "Ruby init...")
    puts "Output: #{output.inspect}"
  end

  def build_callback_runner
    FFI::Function.new(:pointer, [:string]) do |name|  # <- and here
      puts "Inside runner: #{name}"
      FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string("DO YOU READ ME?") # <- and here
    end
  end

end

Foo.new
```

With the C code from the question, this produces:

```
do_some_work param: Ruby init...
Inside runner: Hello from C
callback output: DO YOU READ ME?
Output: "Returned from C"
```

The main issue is memory allocation and freeing. In this case the `MemoryPointer` is subject to garbage collection which will free the string data. I’m fairly sure this is safe as long as the C function doesn’t save the pointer and try to use it later (i.e. GC won’t occur before the C function has completed). If it does you will need to ensure that the string is copied by the function, or look into [wrapping and using `malloc` and `free`](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Pointers#handing-off-memory-to-external-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, looks like this feature is missing from the FFI library (boo)

But it's fairly easy to fix with a pointer to a pointer:

```
// Name: fun.c
// Compiled with: gcc -shared -o fun.o fun.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char* (*callbkfn)(char**, char*); // note the char**

extern char* do_some_work(callbkfn fn, char* name);

char* do_some_work(callbkfn fn, char* userdata) {
  char* callback_output;
  printf("do_some_work param: %s\n", userdata);
  fn(&callback_output, strdup("Hello from C"));
  printf("callback output: %s\n", callback_output);
  return strdup("Returned from C");
}
```

Then change the address of the pointer in rubyland:

```
require 'ffi'

class Foo
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib File.expand_path('fun.o')
  callback :incoming_rpc, [:pointer, :string], :void
  attach_function :do_some_work, [:incoming_rpc, :string], :string, blocking: true

  def initialize
    @callback = build_callback_runner
    output = do_some_work(@callback, "Ruby init...")
    puts "Output: #{output.inspect}"
  end

  def build_callback_runner
    FFI::Function.new(:void, [:pointer, :string]) do |output, input|
      puts "Inside runner: #{input}"
      new_string = FFI::MemoryPointer.from_string("This is my output: #{input.reverse}")
      output.write_pointer new_string.address
    end
  end

end

Foo.new
```

Again, not sure about what memory leaks this might cause, or whether the GC will make that memorypointer address invalid - will go and do my research now!

Comment: FWIW, I've started with a [development branch](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/pull/751) to get an upstream proposal going.